# iPhone OpenGL ES

Tags: c++, iphone, opengl-es

Since I'm not familiar with iPhone development I'd like to know whether it is possible to use OpenGL ES1.0 on the iPhone 3gs rather than 2.0.

I'd like to share a code base across different mobile platforms and not having to deal with the programmable pipeline from OGLES 2.0 could speed up an initial build.

**Update** -- I'm not used to working with OpenGL Es, but is there a always complete backward compatibility or do phones sometimes only support the latest version, eg 2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply call the OpenGL ES 1.0 APIs. The hardware is a full 2.0 device, but the software/driver can implement an OpenGL 1.x pipeline for you.

Comment: Specifically you want OpenGL ES 1.1 with some extensions.  Both the PowerVRSGX (3GS) and MBX (before 3GS) support GL ES 1.1.  Be aware that some of the extensions may be implemented in software (slow) rather than hardware, though; I was drooling over potential VRAM savings with GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture before I figured out that there was a serious performance tradeoff.

See also: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html